# Is it OK to say "use nothing"?

Tags: grammaticality

Is it OK to say "use nothing"? Looks weird to me for some reason, though sentences like "I know nothing about..." are perfectly grammatical, as I know.

Maybe I should replace it with "don't use anything" or something else?

> - In place of `Else If`, use `If`.
> - In place of `Else`, use nothing.
>
> ```
> // Do
> If (!Var1)
>     Return A
> If (!Var2)
>     Return B
> Return C
> ```
>
> ```
> // Don't
> If (!Var1)
>     Return A
> Else If (!Var2)
>     Return B
> Else
>     Return C
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think "use nothing" is perfectly grammatical; as a programmer myself, I think it is more clear to say something different, perhaps "Don't use anything".

(I've always felt that multiple return statements out of a subprogram are a bad idea, but that's not an English issue.)

Comment: I wholeheartedly agree with the programming insight. I disagree with the recommendation tho. Since you are recommending a change, saying "Don't use anything" can be confusing, as it can sound a little smilar to "Don't do anything"  meaning leaving things as they are. I also think *nothing* is the more direct way to convey the intended meaning. What should we use? Nothing

Comment: I see your point. On the other side, programming has numerous keywords that sound odd when put into an English sentence (e.g., null), and 'use nothing' could be taken to mean there is a keyword 'nothing' that's supposed to be put there. There are bound to be other ways to say it that don't imply there is something that should be put there.

Answer (score 2):

It’s fine to say that, though perhaps a little odd as nothing is actually being “used”. As a programmer myself, I’d probably say something like:

> The Else is no longer required.

Answer (score 1):

> > In place of Else If, use If.

Better

> In place of 'Else If', use jus 'If.'
> or
> ... use 'if' all by itself; the Else is not necessary or helpful

(Sorry, I don't know how to do programming formatting)